# Unable to configure Content-Type header from karate

Tags: karate

am trying to configure the header 'Content-Type' from karate and I am not able to do so. I tried these *  configure headers =  {'Content-Type' : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'} and * header Content-Type = 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'. But in the post call I am making , I always get Content-Type: text/plain which is wrong. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, never mind. I got over this by just adding  * header Content-Type = 'application/json'  rather than Content-Type' : 'application/json**;charset=UTF-8. I removed ;charset=UTF-8. If i add this, it breaks. I get an error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MIME type may not contain reserved characters
at org.apache.http.util.Args.check(Args.java:36).

Comment: yep. karate defaults to UTF-8 internally and you don't need it on the headers. but this is I think the second time it has come up on SO - so I've opened an issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/203

Comment: Thank you! that will help others save some debugging time.